# Add a div contains asp Label from code behind in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I tried to add a `div` which contains an `asp:Label` on a button click event.
The following code which I used.

**CODE**

```
string htmlString = "<div><asp:Label ID=\"l1\" runat=\"server\" Text=\"WELCOME\"></asp:Label></div>";
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(htmlString));
```

But I am not able to view that particular `div`.
Please try to solve me this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the markup for a server control like that will not process the server control but simply will put that markup in the produced HTML

You can use a `HTmlGenericControl` to do that

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "WELCOME";

HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

div.Controls.Add(lbl);
Panel1.Controls.Add(div);
```

To add a `DataList` inside the `div` you can do the following

```
DataList dl = new DataList();
//Init your DataList here 
dl.DataSource = dt; // `dt` is a DataTable with my data
dl.DataBind()

HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

div.Controls.Add(dl);
Panel1.Controls.Add(div);
```

Comment: Actually I want to add a DataList inside that div.

Comment: The same concept applies here, instead of a `Label` you can use a `DataList` and no other changes are required, I updated my code snippet

Comment: One more doubt. How to bind data to this datalist?

Comment: I added a small snippet on how to bind data, if you need more help on that part I think it would be better to start a new question (so that more people will see it).

Answer (score 1):

You can not use server controls to output-stream directly. You need the [Html Generic Controls](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_htmlgeneric.asp) for that.

You can declare a control as follows

```
HtmlContainerControl Container = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
```

and then add it to the Panel1 as follow

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(Container);
```

You can add as may controls in `div` note that the `Label` render as `span` on html so you need to use a span rather than a label.

Combining all you can write as below

```
HtmlContainerControl Container = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
HtmlContainerControl Span= new HtmlGenericControl("span");
//set the property here
Span.Attributes.Add("innerHtml", "WELCOME");

Contriner.Controls.Add(Span);
Panel1.Controls.Add(Container);
```

Answer (score 1):

all asp controls will be rendered as html controls in the browser.. your code will be rendered as

> `<span id="l1">WELCOME</span>`

but as you are using the LiteralControl it only adds a html type control.. 
so your code won't be parsed.. and the result will be a invalid html tag..

Create a label asp control and add to the panel instead

> ```
>       Label label1 = new Label();
>       label1.Text = "WELCOME";
>       Panel1.Controls.Add(label1);
> ```